# App Distributed Ad Hoc and Release Version

Tags: ios, adhoc

I am currently working on an update to an iOS application that was released via enterprise distribution.  We have already released version one, and are now adding new features for version 2.  We intend to selectively distribute a beta version for real world testing, but this beta would have to live alongside version 1.  Is there any conflict between two iOS applications that have the same AppID, but the released version being signed with a distribution certificate, and the one distributed ad hoc?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1618717/620197) post, but it does not address my specific case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would like to distribute an adhoc build without overriding the current production build you can change the bundle identifier. Once this is changed it will not install over the production build, instead it'll be another app.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, if they have the same bundle ID, the more recently installed version (typically your ad-hoc distributed version) is simply installed over the other app.  I have updated devices during my time as a developer that had app store installs with ad-hoc and it has simply overwritten the installed one